Guest users are not able to create Cart
I'm trying to implement Guest Browsing and checkout for a D2C commerce store following this article (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/commerce/salesforce-commerce/guide/b2b-b2c-comm-set-up-guest-checkout-headless.html). I'm following the postman collection (https://github.com/sandragolden/sf-scom-postman-collection) to create Cart for Guest User. Somehow I'm getting the below error saying that the Guest users are not permitted to perform this operation. I'have tried passing the GuestBuyerProfile Id as effectiveAccountId in the request body but still getting the same error. I'm using api Version 49.0 or 50.0 for this request. I'have tried using above api versions but got no luck. The standard guest checkout is working and the cart is getting created using the website so I'm not sure why the api is returning this error
Really appreciate for helping me!!
